# How to schedule datebase backup in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, backup

I want to schedule datebase backup in IBM DB2.
Is it possible?
I found some information about it from documentation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=commands-backup-database
I would like to schedule it to happen every 3 months and saved in a specific location.

Thanks for the answers and best regards.

Comment: What is your Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows/cloud) and Db2-server-version?  Which scheduler do you want to use? Is your database highly-available?  This is a basic Database Administration question , not programming, consider using dba.stackexchange.com  and improving your question with missing facts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple choices for that.

You may use your OS task scheduler (at, cron).

Db2 has its own task scheduler called Admin Task Scheduler (ATS).
You may use the [ADMIN_TASK_ADD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-admin-task-add-procedure-schedule-new-task) routine to schedule **online** backup like described in the *Example 1* after setting up Db2 ATS.

You may set up [Automatic database backup](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=overview-automatic-database-backup) (both offline and online) as well.